# jquery redirect issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems in redirecting page with jquery. I have a variable `url` which contains `localhost/abc#123`. When i write `document.location.href = url;`, the page redirects to `localhost/abc` leaving `#123`. How to resolve this issue

Comment: What browser is this being tested in? Try using `window.location.href` instead - just for debugging purposes

Comment: it's work for me in Firefox and chrome and IE8. document.location.href=url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = "http://bing.com/refresh/test.html#123";

document.location.href=url
```

it's work fine for me in my firefox. do you have tried to debug what happen on your side. I have test this code in IE8 + firefox + chrome.  I hope it's will work fine for you.

if this code doesn't work on your side then try

```
window.location.replace(url)
```

as your comment it's look like you have used Anchor so tried this one.

```
$("#myanchor").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

// redirect code here
});
```

Comment: i called this event on anchor click, page gets redirected to anchor link... instead of `url`

Comment: @KodePlex Really? Why wouldn't you post your code for the anchor link click event, or explain that originally?

Comment: I thing you should use e.preventDefault() to prevent the browser to go to anchor link. please check my answer again and I hope it's will solve your answer.

Comment: @KodePlex check this http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3 I am sure it's will help you to solve your problem.